# PHP include Javascript-generated filename?

Tags: javascript, php

```
while(x<=num_of_cpkgs){
  var cpkg_navtray = '\'navtrays/' + cpkg_array[x] + '.html\'';
  <?php include ?> cpkg_navtray <?php ; ?>;
  x++;
}
```

`cpkg_array` contains potentially multiple file names. I'm wondering if there's a way to include a Javascript-generated filename in a PHP include statement like this?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work like this.

**TL;DR:**

You need AJAX calls for this.

**Longer:**

When you load a page in your Browser, the server send you the file. If the file is a php file, then it calls the php to process the file. After the file is processed the server send it to you as a static file.

With JS you can do some interaction to the website. Until now you probably got used to sending each file as a GET or POST data with a form. With JS you have to make an XMLHttpRequest to create a dynamic request and your page is won't be refreshed again however you will get the response as a variable in JS.

Read all about this [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp).

Comment: How would this be accomplished via AJAX? Would you utilize JQuery's .load?

Comment: you can use the jQuery's ajax.