# PHP include dynamically generated filename?

Tags: php

```
while($x<=$num_of_cpkgs){
  $cpkg_navtray = '\'' . $cpkg_array[$x] . '.html\'';
  include $cpkg_navtray;
  $x++;
}
```

I'm getting an error when I try this ... it works when I manually include the same value however ... for example, if `$cpkg_navtray = 'test.html'`, I'm getting an error; however, when I directly include 'test.html' like `include 'test.html';`, it works. Why?

Comment: File names tend not to have single-quotes at the start and end...

Comment: What your code is actually `include "'test.html'";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need quotes in filename variable -

```
$cpkg_navtray = $cpkg_array[$x] . '.html';
```

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

[Looking same Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37192502/php-include-javascript-generated-filename) but tag and desire different: Jut do these, just a simple concatenate.

```
while($x<=$num_of_cpkgs){
  $cpkg_navtray = $cpkg_array[$x].'.html';
  include $cpkg_navtray;
  $x++;
}
```